# Single Server Multiple Virtual PCs remote access to Virtual PCs

Tags: remote-desktop, virtual-machines, vnc

We want to setup one mega server (8GB RAM, Quad Core Processor) and install Virtual Machines for the following tasks.

1. Virtual Machine for SVN server, Bug tracker
2. Virtual Machine for Sharepoint portal development
3. Virtual machine for IIS deployment for client access

we will be port forwarding request to virtual machine instance.

Can two developer can access different virtual machine using VNC at same time?

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple developers access different VMs using VNC and port forwarding, but I'd suggest assigning different IPs to each VM and using a bridged rather than NAT'd network configuration.

If you use NAT, the behaviour of accessing a VM differs depending on if you're accessing it from the main network or a different VM.

I'd also suggest RDP rather than VNC for remote access. The performance tends to be better, and it's one less piece of software to maintain.